# Filesystem check during installation takes long time

Tags: system-installation, 14.04

Filesystem check, as I install Ubuntu 14.04, took 9 hours and the installation didn't continue. How can i fix it? Tried to install it with windows but on different partition.

Comment: Please **edit the question** and add more details. Is this installation running from within Windows or is it booted from a Live USB/DVD? Did the computer come with Windows 8 pre-installed? Which version of Windows is it running now? Did you choose "Install side by side" or some other option while trying to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Long filesystem check almost always mean physical damage on the hard drive. Don't install on existing partition, set up a new one and try to install again. If problem still occurs, them start looking for new hard drive, because your current one is in its agony.